# How to set state boundary symbology for polygons in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, symbology

I'm trying to symbolize a state polygon layer in ArcGIS Pro 3.1. I feel like I should be able to do it basically the same way I've done it in ArcMap, which is to select a line symbol to be used for the outline of the polygon, and in ArcMap there were standard boundary line symbols available for that which I would like to use. This image illustrates how I would do this in ArcMap. How can I do the same in Pro?
[image]

So I think I have two separate questions:

1. How to apply a preset line symbol to a polygon outline in Pro?
2. How to get the standard state boundary line symbol (the one I circled) and other similar symbols to be available as preset line symbols in Pro? (currently I can't find the line symbol I want in Pro, even for a polyline layer - do I need to download it from somewhere?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import the style file from ArcMap into your ArcGIS Pro project, Click on to enlarge video below:

[image: How to add style file]

Comment: Nice video. Yeah, this answers part 2. I'm kind of disappointed that those symbols from ArcMap aren't standard in Pro, but I guess that's how it is.

Now, anyone know how to do part 1 (apply a line symbol to a polygon outline? If not, I think I'll try this: Set the polygon symbol they way I want it in ArcMap, then save that as a custom style, then import that style into Pro so I can use it for polygons in Pro. Not ideal, but might be the best I can do.

Comment: @MattLeonard you are best asking your other question as a separate question. Format of this forum is strictly 1 question only.

Answer (score 0):

As for Part 1 of my question (maybe I should have posted as a separate question but I had one ultimate goal which I realized had two components)... I'm going to paste the following which I got on reddit from user Insurance-Purple which I found helpful:

> Apparently polygon borders are strokes and not line symbols in Pro,
> and so you cannot apply predefined line symbology to strokes.
>
> https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/how-can-i-choose-symbology-for-polygon-outline/td-p/52160
>
> https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/stroke-symbol-layers.htm